# AngularJS - How do I check a checkbox inside of a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, directive

I am new to AngularJS so I am still trying to get a grasp on the best practices and the "Angular way" of doing things. With that being said, here is my situation:

I am trying to submit an AngularJS form. Part of the form is a list of blog names that I want the user to choose from. Inside each `<li>` is a checkbox. When the user clicks on the `li`, I want to check the checkbox so that when the form is submitted, it records the selected blog names.

```
<li>
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{ image }}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ name }}
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="blogs[]" value="{{ name }}" style="display: none">
</li>
```

Now, I need this exact list item in 3 different lists. So I thought the way I should do it, is make it a directive:

**The JS**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('blogSelect', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<li ng-click="onClick()"><div><img ng-src="{{ image }}" /></div><div >{{ name }}</div><input type="checkbox" name="blogs[]" value="{{ name }}" style="display: none"></li>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            image: '@image',
            name: '@name'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
        $scope.onClick = function() {
            $element.toggleClass("selected");

            var checkbox = $element.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            checkbox.attr("checked", !checkbox.attr("checked"));
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

**The HTML**

```
<ul ng-if="vm.blogs.length">
   <blog-select ng-repeat="blog in vm.blogs"
       name="{{blog.name}}"
       image="/url/to/img/{{ blog.name }}.jpg">
   </blog-select>
</ul>
```

Something doesn't seem right here. The checkbox variable in the onClick function is `undefined`. After some research, I don't think I am doing it the correct way. Should I be controlling the checkbox based on an array in my model (where the `vm.blogs` is coming from)? I can't seem to find anything that describes what to do with a custom checkbox directive in my situation.

But then again, maybe I'm not even going about it the right way? Any wisdom, insight, and/or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking in a DOM-manipulation manner rather than an Angular MV* manner.

It's true that you have an element which you wish to bind to behavior

You have a directive that encapsulates and defines the behavior, but you're reaching for the "how do I poke values into the DOM?" tools that you're accustomed to, rather than the "how do I expose information in an object model through scope to the DOM?"

You should manipulate the value the element is bound to in the directive, therefore adding the `ng-checked` directive to your input and using its binding to control the checked state of the checkbox is what you're looking for.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ngChecked` directive to compare the states of the inputs: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-checked.asp

Official documentation:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked